# How do you run CruiseControl on MacOSX

Tags: java, macos, jetty, cruisecontrol

What am I doing wrong?

1. [Download Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/download.html)
2. Unzip it -- **Now it's in ~/Downloads/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4**
3. Run ./cruisecontrol.sh

I see the server spinning up.  The service binds to port 8080.  So I wait a moment, then I go over to port 8080 using my browser.

This is what I see:

Error 404 - Not Found.

No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:
/cc-config ---> org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@519549e{/cc-config,file:/Users/darryl/Downloads/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/webapps/cc-config/}
/cruisecontrol ---> org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@420253af{/cruisecontrol,file:/Users/darryl/Downloads/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/webapps/cruisecontrol/}
/dashboard ---> org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@26c42804{/dashboard,file:/Users/darryl/Downloads/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/webapps/dashboard/}
/documentation ---> org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@181f327e{/documentation,file:/Users/darryl/Downloads/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/webapps/documentation/}

Comment: So did you visit, e.g., http://localhost:8080/cruisecontrol, or one of the other valid contexts listed?

Comment: I feel silly.  I didn't do that. It works now.  Thanks!